# My computer crashes when I start a steam game

Tags: windows-7, directx, steam

When I start a game, for example CS: GO, my computer crashes. First the screen goes black screen, then it crashes and starts again by it self. I think its something to do with DirectX, because when I look at the delete stuff list, I can't actually see DirectX anywhere.

I hope someone can help me figure out the problem

Other steam games: MW3 - Saints Row 3. These are 3 steam games that crash my pc when I start them.

My graphic card is a Nvidia Geforce GTX 560. I have previously had some problems with it, for example when I am watching a Youtube video there's popping purple/blue squares randomly on my screen.

I don't know about the CPU stress.

Comment: Does this happen with all games you launch? E.g. all non-steam games, 2D (low graphics) steam games? Does it happen when you stress the GPU (e.g. run a graphical benchmark). Is anything logged in the eventlog ([start], `run`, `eventvwr.msc`, under windows logs). ...

Comment: About the video problem: does it happen only on YouTube, can you watch local movies without that problem?

Comment: Ah. That is a rather important piece of information.

Comment: Uninstall the Update KB2859537 and lok if this fixes it: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_update/kb2859537-bsod/2787e746-cea2-41ae-b2fc-c2979c1c03e1?page=1&tm=1376555848575

Answer (score 1):

Lets summarise:

- When you use the video card for low intensity tasks you get popping purple, blue squares random on my screen.
- When you use the video card for more demanding tasks the whole computer crashes.

I think you already found your problem.

- Check if the fans on the card still run.
- Check if all power cables are connected (if you are lucky it just is not getting enough power).
- Check for exploded capacitors.

  If you find none of these (or can't replace them yourself) then replace the videocard. Optionally after testing it in another computer. One which you would not mind loosing if something breaks badly.

Comment: Actually, the video artifacts problem can be unrelated. I remember it happened to me on Win8DP and there were some questions about similar problems on SU.

Comment: True, but unlikely. The logical way would be to diagnose that first. And the syndromes match those of a graphical card which gets to little power. Especially one which [need 150W](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gtx-560/specifications) and who will need extra 6-pin or extra 8-pin connectors.

Comment: It depends whether the popping purple, blue squares are on the entire LCD screen (the actual youtube page) or just in the video.

When you stream (most of the time) the entire image is not sent, rather just the change (or delta) between the frames. This means that the more history there is (i.e. use that hue of blue from pixel X in frame Y), the less sent. When a stream is paused/interrupted for whatever reason, this "history" is lost and will need to be re-transmitted, sometimes resulting in the aforementioned artifacts.

Answer (score 0):

**If the game crashes:** 
Try this [steam support](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=5014-OGNM-7613). Try the `-safe launch` option.

Using the -safe launch option

1. Open Steam
2. Go to the "Library"
3. Right-click the game that needs to be reconfigured
4. Select "Properties" from the menu
5. Click the "Set launch options..." button
6. Remove any launch options currently shown.
7. Type -safe in the box and select OK.
8. Launch the game and test the issue again.

Once the game is launching, you can remove -safe and start modifying your video options one-by-one to determine which option was causing the graphical issue that you are encountering.

**If the computer crashes:**
You have problems with your graphic card. I dont think its only DirectX related.
Make a stress-test like recommended. Check out the temperature of your GPU etc.
And follow Hennes answer for more troubleshooting...

Comment: A valid answer if the problem is with steam. However the OP just added this to his or her post:  "My graphic card: NVIDIA Geforce GTX 560 - **Theres has been some problems with it, when i sitting and watch a Youtube vid. theres popping purple, blue squares random on my screen**."

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be your video card, bad drivers or not.  I went out and bought a new card, installed the newest drivers and still had the same problem.  It wasn't until I disabled steam guard that my rebooting problems went away, for nearly 6 months now.  Go to your account details, scroll down to manage steam guard, select "Turn Steam Guard off."  It isn't recommended, but my rebooting problems are gone.  It's a problem Steam needs to address.  It's at least worth a shot.